# I'm trying to use fmod library. When I pass the path value that contains Korean, 'file not found' error message is output

Tags: encoding, mp3, fmod

When I pass the path value that contains Korean, 'file not found' error message is output.

```
char songPath[500];
strcpy_s(songPath, sizeof(songPath), MusicBox::getInstance()->container()->getMusic(i)->path);
result = pFmod->createSound(songPath, FMOD_ACCURATETIME, NULL, &music[i]);
```

when I check the variable 'songpath', the songPath has a correct value.
but createSound function does not returns a 'FMOD_OK'.
How do I solve this problem?
could you give me some hint?

Comment: FMOD needs UTF-8 encoded strings, you need to ensure the proper encoding.

Comment: ㄴ I slove the problem! thank you!!